# "It was not possible to connect to the redis server" Bitnami hosted on Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, redis, bitnami

### Problem:

When I try to connect from my local machine to a Redis VM hosted on Google Cloud, the connection is refused.

**QUESTION:** How can I connect to Redis installed on a private VM in GCP after successfully connecting to the VPC via a VPN?

### Setup:

- VM hosted in Google Cloud without public IP
- Redis installed on VM by deploying the VM using the Bitnami package from GCP Marketplace
- Firewall rule added to GCP targeting my VM, allowing TCP ingress traffic on port 6379 for all IP ranges
- VPN setup using OpenVPN to tunnel into GCP VPC from local machine (Windows)

### What I know:

- Redis is running... if I SSH into my VM and run `redis-cli`, everything works as expected
- VPN is working... from my local machine, I can successfully `ping` my VM when connected to the VPN
- Redis config comments out the binding to `127.0.0.0` to (theoretically) open it up to all bindings, after which I restarted Redis on my VM (I think)
- The password I'm using is correct

### What doesn't work:

#### StackExchange.Redis:

```
var redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("my.ip.to.vm", config =>
{
    config.Password = "my-redis-password";
});
```

#### Command Line from Local Machine (using `redis-cli` npm package):

```
rdcli -h my.ip.to.vm -a my-redis-password
```

### Recap

- What am I missing?
- How can I connect to Redis installed on a private VM in GCP after successfully connecting to the VPC via a VPN?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution (this is embarrassing):

1. Stop VM
2. Start VM